# setting global font scaling (which will affect menu bars, editors, such as gvim)

Tags: unity, fonts, gui, appearance

I remember setting something that affected the font size in GUI elements such as menu bars as well as text areas in editors (such as the default font setting in gvim).

I tried to look into the "appearance" settings but could not find it.

Do you remember that setting? How to tweak it?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This setting is under the "Display Setting" in System Settings. You can get to it by searching "Display". Here is what it looks like:

[image]